# UI Offset within GMSPlacePickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker, gmsplace

I have implemented a `GMSPlacesClient` and `GMSPlacePickerViewController`, and the setup functions fine. However, there appears to be a vertical offset within the UI that creates an aesthetic issue: in search, the first item in the table is cut off, and after returning to the map, there is a black space at the top of the view.

I am pushing the view using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:];`

[image: Cutoff item]

[image: Unwanted gap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Translucent option is checked on your navigation bar inside navigation controller.

I had the same problem and realize that the Translucent is not checked.

Checking Translucent solved my problem.

I'm pretty sure this can help.

Comment: This worked perfectly. You saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I helped.